# Facet for simple math expressions

Tags: c++, parsing, stream

I've built simple math expression facet which ignores any character except numbers and operators listed below:

> plus, minus, multiply, divide, degree, left bracket, right bracket, assignment

I'm worrying about hardcoded values of the operators and numbers. I believe that loop from '0' to '9' will not fail since most compilers use ASCII. Despite that, it would be great to make the code more portable.

Is there any opportunity to improve performance? It seems like control over performance is at standard library implementation.

Note that instance of `ignore_punctuation` doesn't leak [due to wording of facet library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17779731/4593721).

Code and use case:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

struct ignore_punctuation :std::ctype<char>
{
    static const mask* make_table()
    {
        static std::vector<mask> v(classic_table(), classic_table() + table_size);
        for (auto& elem : v)
        {
            elem |= blank;
        }

        for (auto c = '0'; c <= '9'; ++c)
        {
            v[c] &= ~blank;
        }

        v['+'] &= ~blank;
        v['-'] &= ~blank;
        v['*'] &= ~blank;
        v['/'] &= ~blank;
        v['='] &= ~blank;
        v['^'] &= ~blank;
        v['('] &= ~blank;
        v[')'] &= ~blank;

        return &v.front();
    }

    ignore_punctuation(std::size_t refs = 0) : ctype(make_table(), false, refs) {}
};

int main()
{
    std::string s = "a+(7+1)+5-9=11ssd";

    std::istringstream input(s);
    input.imbue(std::locale(input.getloc(), new ignore_punctuation));

    std::string token;
    while (input >> token)
    {
        std::cout << token;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's good practice in C++ to pass in `new object` as a parameter (may cause memory leakage?). I would just define `ignore_punctuation* obj = new ignore_punctuation;` and pass in obj. Then I would call `delete obj;`.

Comment: @ArchieGertsman, [not in this case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17779660/who-is-responsible-for-deleting-the-facet). I encourage you to read till the end. Just ignore the question, answer is what matters.

Comment: Your loop works because the C standard guarantees that the digits 0 .. 9 are sequential in the character set, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/29381136/1187415.

Comment: @MartinR, thanks. Good point for the review!